# Exception when running TFS 2015 custom build task

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2015, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-pipelines

I have developed a plugin (extension) for TFS 2015.
The plugin is actually a custom build task that can be added as a step in the build process.

The problem is that when I developed my plugin I used TFS 2015 **update 2.1** but my users work with **update 2.0** and they see this strange error shortly after the plugin starts running during the process of asking for the user inputs.

When this line is executed:

```
var build = tl.getInput(MyConstants.SomeInput, true);
```

This error occurs:

```
17:46:13.932774 Process logging event with task handler. 17:46:13.932774
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
17:46:13.932774 System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.    
17:46:13.932774    at System.Text.StringBuilder.AppendFormatHelper(IFormatProvider provider, String format, ParamsArray args)  
17:46:13.932774    at System.String.FormatHelper(IFormatProvider provider, String format, ParamsArray args)    
17:46:13.932774    at System.String.Format(IFormatProvider provider, String format, Object[] args)    
17:46:13.932774    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Agent.Worker.Common.BaseContext.LogMessageWithDecoration(LoggingVerbosity verbosity, String decoration, String message, Object[] args) 17:46:13.932774    at System.Text.StringBuilder.AppendFormatHelper(IFormatProvider provider, String format, ParamsArray args)    
17:46:13.932774    at System.String.FormatHelper(IFormatProvider provider, String format, ParamsArray args)    
17:46:13.932774    at System.String.Format(IFormatProvider provider, String format, Object[] args)    
17:46:13.932774    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Agent.Worker.Common.BaseContext.LogMessageWithDecoration(LoggingVerbosity verbosity, String decoration, String message, Object[] args) 17:46:13.932774
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I was able to reproduce this error and it exists only in update 2.0 and gone after I updated to 2.1. I have searched but didn't see anything in the update 2.1 change log that implies any bug fix related to my error.

What am I missing?

Comment: Is your extension a cross-platform Build tasks?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what do you mean. I wrote a plugin based on Javascript (running on Node of course) to trigger some API. I'm guessing it can be called cross-platform but I'm not sure exactly what does Microsoft mean in cross-platform.

Comment: I was trying to say whether your extension has cross-platform Build tasks. Cross-platform Build task means this task can be used on multiple platforms, like Windows, OSX or Linux.

Comment: My extension has a Build task written in JavaScript running on Node so i'm assuming it's cross-platform. But, Is there any TFS 2015 build task that is not cross-platform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your extension have cross-platform Build tasks. You can check [Team Foundation Server 2015 Update 2.1 Fixed Bugs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/6da268be-c72c-43a5-95ad-9f28c1ef400c). There is a bug fixed under Build for Update 2:

> Extensions that have cross-platform Build tasks do not work.